# JavaFX: Can't center the row cells horizontally inside the GridPane

Tags: java, javafx

I have this JavaFX code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Test extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Label nameLabel = new Label("Customer Name:");
        Label resultsLabel = new Label("Results:");

        Button taxesButton = new Button("Calculate the Taxes");
        Button interestButton = new Button("Calculate the Interest");

        TextField salaryField = new TextField();

        TextField resultsField = new TextField();
        resultsField.setEditable(false);


        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();

        gridPane.add(nameLabel, 0, 0);
        gridPane.add(salaryField, 1, 0);

        gridPane.add(taxesButton, 0, 1);
        gridPane.add(interestButton, 1, 1);
        GridPane.setHalignment(taxesButton, HPos.CENTER);
        GridPane.setHalignment(interestButton, HPos.RIGHT);

        gridPane.add(resultsLabel, 0, 2);
        gridPane.add(resultsField, 1, 2);


        gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

        gridPane.setVgap(10);
        gridPane.setHgap(10);


        stage.setTitle("Calculations");
        Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 400, 150);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I would like it to look like this (the first column is centered):

[image]

I tried adding `Pos.Center` but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [ColumnConstraints](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/ColumnConstraints.html) for that like this:

```java
ColumnConstraints columnConstraint = new ColumnConstraints();
columnConstraint.setHalignment(HPos.CENTER);
gridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(columnConstraint);
```